# Missing Required Icon File - Application Loader

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, application-loader, fastlane

When using the Application Loader application to upload a .ipa file to iTunes Connect for review I encounter an error:

[image]

However, in my `Images.xcassets` folder in my AppIcon Image Set there is an icon set for iPad Pro and it is a .png at 167x167.

[image][image]

If the image is there and it is added to the target's asset folder, why is this error showing up? What might I be missing?

Notes:

- The .ipa file is being generated by Fastlane. Version 1.99.0
- When I look inside the .ipa file the icon file is not there. It appears the icon file is not being added to the bundle.
- I am not using Xamarin
- I have tried adding `CFBundleIconFiles` to the `Info.plist`. It did not work.
- I have tried cleaning the project, updating Xcode and restarting my computer. It did not work.

Comment: already you checked the section `App Icons Source`? in TARGET-> General tab

Comment: Yes, it is set to the correct Image Set